# Javascript Syntax of function, issue in Internet Explorer <= 11 (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syntax

This code on Internet explorer <= 11, doesn't work (only on edge works)

```
Bus.$on('UpdateCartData', (event) => {
  this.cart = event.cart;
  this.cart_options = event.cart_options;
});
```

Says SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

When I transform it through Babel polyfill, suggests to transform it to:

```
Bus.$on('UpdateCartData', function (event) {
```

As this doesn't shows Syntax error anymore, but the logic and functionallity stops working even on Google Chrome.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Pretty surely that's not the only transformation that Babel did.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Replaced (this.cart = event.cart;) with (undefined.cart = event.cart;)

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate link helped me to understand the structure.

"Defined in ECMA Script 6, arrow-functions adopt the this binding from the enclosing (function or global) scope."

so should be:

```
var vm = this;
      Bus.$on('UpdateCartData', function (event) {
        vm.cart = event.cart;
        vm.cart_options = event.cart_options;
      });
}
```